# Next.js i18n - pages are not automatically redirected

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization

Why is the homepage redirected correctly but the subpages not?

Example. My browser language is set to French:

1. If I open the homepage `some.com`, I am automatically redirected to `some.com/fr` - and that's good!
2. If I open a subpage, like `some.com/about`, I am **NOT** redirected to `some.com/fr/about`, I'm staying on `some.com/about` in English and this is bad.

**My next.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['fr', 'en'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  },
};
```

Comment: Show me the next.config.js file, Please.

Comment: is in the description, that's all I have

Answer (score 1):

You can control this behaviour via middleware.

Add `middleware.ts` at the same level as your `pages` directory.

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/;

export const middleware = (request: NextRequest) => {
  const { nextUrl, headers } = request;

  // Early return if it is a public file such as an image
  if (PUBLIC_FILE.test(nextUrl.pathname)) {
    return undefined;
  }

  // Get language part of the accept-language header
  const language =
    headers
      .get("accept-language")
      ?.split(",")?.[0]
      .split("-")?.[0]
      .toLowerCase() || "en";

  // Cloned url to work with
  const url = nextUrl.clone();

  if (
    nextUrl.locale === "en" &&
    language === "fr"
  ) {
    url.pathname = `/fr${nextUrl.pathname}`;
    return NextResponse.redirect(url);
  }

  return undefined;
};
```

Inspired by https://www.erichowey.dev/writing/advanced-internationalization-with-nextjs-and-middleware/

Comment: You saved me! Thanks!